# How to make a section in gitlab-ci job log on powershell/windows docker image

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

I would like to ask how to create a collapsible sections in a job log on gitlab-ci.
I tried to follow https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#custom-collapsible-sections but it didn't work for me.
My docker image for the pipeline is windows based so instead of

```
script:
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_start:`date +%s`:my_first_section\r\e[0KHeader of the 1st collapsible section"
    - echo 'this line should be hidden when collapsed'
    - echo -e "\e[0Ksection_end:`date +%s`:my_first_section\r\e[0K"
```

I used

```
script:
    - echo "\e[0Ksection_start:$(get-date -uformat %s):my_first_section\r\e[0KHeader of the 1st collapsible section"
    - echo 'this line should be hidden when collapsed'
    - echo "\e[0Ksection_end:$(get-date -uformat %s):my_first_section\r\e[0K"
```

The problem seems to be in the escape characters.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: There is a solution here: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/creating-collapsible-sections-in-pipeline-shell-scripts/34611